# Can differential backups interfere with the SSIS job process?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to ask about the differential backup that happens in SQL Server 2012.
What I want to ask are when the job is started, will the backup plan will stop all SSIS job?

Comment: Are you asking hypothetically? Or because you are experiencing issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want to ask are when the job is started, will the backup plan will stop all SSIS job?

There is no actual need to stop SSIS jobs during the backup.
However, it still can be planned to run in own maintenance time window, which not interferes with user jobs due to reason stated below.

> Backup task is fully online operation. It will not cause any locks or downtimes.
> However, it can impact performance of your SSIS package because it can hit IO and network subsystems of the server.